# ActiveMQ Dead Connection issue

Tags: apache, tcp, connection, activemq-classic, wso2-esb

Hi am working on ActiveMQ 5.10.0 they are curtain process which will connect through a TCP connection and send messages to a queue and also topic subscriptions,Total max connections are around 10000.

After some usage am facing error as max connections exceeded in activeMQ,i have gone through activemq console and found a lot of the TCP connections are still alive with active status as true and this connections pileup  to 10000 and ActiveMQ throws error as max connection exceeded.

why are this connections are staying forever with status true how to get rid of this connections is there any way to kill this dead connections or make connection expire after some duration.

Thank You..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever a JMS client wants to connect with the a MQ broker then typical code is like this:

```
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
```

Now, once JMS client (producer/consumer) is done if it doesn't close the connection then that JMS client will still remain connected with the MQ broker and will occupy a connection with the MQ broker. Now, in your case looks like your JMS client code "could be faulty" and not closing the connection, so you need to check your JMS client code and get the connections closed like below.

```
if (connection != null) {
      connection.close();
}
```

Now, having said that if you have message listeners in your JMS client then it is expected that connection would remain open, but in case if those connections are totally inactive after some time then you can **specify maximum inactivity duration for the connections using `wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration`**, for this when you are creating a connection with MQ broker then you should create like this `cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
    "tcp://localhost:61616?wireFormat=openwire&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=<<whatever_value_you_want>>");`

Read [this](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/configuring.html) ActiveMQ documentation for more details.

---

**As a FYI** - maximum number of connections in a ActiveMQ broker is defined using its configuration file `activemq.xml`, inside that you have `transportConnectors` element where you defined maximum connection (`?maximumConnections=1000`) as shown below, so just in case if you have appropriate system resources and you have capacity to get more client connections then you can increase.

```
<transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

Comment: Hi @hagrawal thank you for the replay, As u said  i have checked with my code all connections are getting closed connection.close(); , case1 : Actually the thing is when a user do login  in the web gets subscribed to a topic through a tcp connection it is not getting closed as it should when the user log outs or session expires.

Comment: case 2:when placing a message in queue end user internet connectivity gets disturbed and the MQ is unable to send ack to the requested used  so the connection stays. any changes can be made in activemq.xml that after a perod of time close the connection.

Comment: For your case 1: as you have mentioned, clearly issue is that when user logs out or if session expires then you have to close the connection. For case 2: like I said you can specify maximum inactivity duration, also can you timeout parameter in similar way, read here - http://activemq.apache.org/tcp-transport-reference.html . And looking at your case I think you should configure slow consumer, read here - https://planet.jboss.org/post/coming_in_activemq_5_9_a_new_way_to_abort_slow_consumers